# Valuation diagram of scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes, then if $f$ is quasi-compact, then there exist a valuation ring $A$ and its fraction field $K$ satisfying the following commutative diagram. The proof that I know uses the scheme theoretic image. The existence is used to prove valuation criteria of universally closedness and separateness.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\text{Spec} K @>>> X\\
@VVV@VV{f}V \\
\text{Spec} A @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$

But if we don't assume $f$ is quasi-compact, then does there still exist $A$ and such a commutative diagram?

Comment: This is (essentially) Proposition 5.5.2 in EGA I, and there is no hypothesis on $f$.

Comment: @abx Could you please tell me the title of section 5.5 in your EGA I? In my edition of EGA I, section 5.5 is "Critères de séparation" and there is only corollary 5.5.2 which says that restriction of separated morphism on subscheme is separated. Thank you.

Comment: I was referring to the Springer edition; 5.5 is "critères valuatifs".